# Best practice method to find execution time in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, benchmarking

I'm interested in the best/standard way to find the execution time of my Zend Framework app. Currently I'm starting the timer on the public/index.php then registering it in Zend_Registry, for a later call, which the layout then uses to calculate the total time.

Is there a better way to do this? I know this isn't even entirely accurate, as there is still (or at least, can be) some execution in the postDispatch() which will be ran after the view is rendered.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up adding

```
$appStartTime = microtime();
```

before the bootstrapper got intsantiated, and put

```
global $appStartTime;
@list( $startMilli, $startSeconds, $endMilli, $endSeconds) = explode(' ',$appStartTime . ' ' . microtime());
$generateTime = ($endSeconds+$endMilli)-($startSeconds+$startMilli);
printf( '. Generated in %.3fs', $generateTime);
if ($generateTime > 1) // one second
{
    Zend_Registry::get( 'logger' )->warn( 'Long page load time of ' . $generateTime . ' on ' . Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRequestUri() );
}
```

at the end of my layout.phtml as the last thing before the closing body tag

Answer (score 3):

I myself use [webgrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind) and xdebug profiling. This gives info not only about total execution time, but also e.g. how many times a given method was executed, what was the time of this execution, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into enabling a real code profiler like [XHProf](http://mirror.facebook.net/facebook/xhprof/doc.html).

Comment: While that would be nice for some things, I don't really think it would be usable with outputting the execution time into the view.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems more like a profiler, instead of just showing execution time on the page.